# Looking for a combinatorial proof for an identity involving $q$-Catalan triangles

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

Let $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ be the Catalan numbers. Following my earlier [post on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383314/looking-for-a-combinatorial-proof-for-a-catalan-identity), one fine colleague asked me if there is a $q$-analogue of the identity formed by the so-called Shapiro's Catalan triangles
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\frac{k}n\binom{2n}{n-k}\right]^2=C_{2n-1}$$
Unfortunately, it did not map out for me. The closest I have come up with is a $q$-analogue of $\sum_{k=1}^nk\left[\frac{k}n\binom{2n}{n-k}\right]^2=\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$ for which I like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is there a combinatorial or conceptual proof of this identity?
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n q^{(k-1)^2}\frac{[2k]}{1+q^n} \left[\frac{[k]}{[n]} \binom{2n}{n-k}_q\right]^2
> = \binom{2n-1}{n-1}_q \binom{2n-2}{n-1}_q,$$
> where $[k]=1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^{k-1}$ and $\binom{n}k_q=\frac{[n]}{[k]\,[n-k]}$.

Comment: Should the terms in the first sum be squared?

Comment: In your previous question, you write the same equality but with the terms in the sum squared. This seems strange to me.

Comment: @SamHopkins: I now understand what you meant. Yes, you are right there. Corrected.

Comment: Not sure if this is of any help towards a combinatorial proof, but $1+q^n=[2n]/[n]$, so the identity may be rewritten as $$\sum_{k=1}^n q^{(k-1)^2}[2k] \left[\frac{[k]}{[n]} \binom{2n}{n-k}_q\right]^2 = \binom{2n}{n}_q \binom{2n-2}{n-1}_q.$$

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein: that looks fine and perhaps would help.